# Pre-image of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve the following problem:
In which topologies (uniform, product, box) are the following functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^\omega}$ continuous?

$f(t)=(t,2t,3t,....)$

$g(t)=(t,t,t,.......)$

$h(t)= (t,\frac{1}{2}t, \frac{1}{3}t,...)$

I am having trouble with the box topology and uniform topology. In my solutions it says for the box topology consider, $B=(-1,1)\times (\frac{-1}{4}.\frac{1}{4})\times\ldots$ has pre-image of {0} for all the functions. But how do we know this? Doesn't this depend on different values of $t$ though for each function?
For uniform topology, is there a nice way to construct the open balls?

( I have asked a similar question before. Based on my understanding from the answers over there I am trying to solve this problem and am stuck!)

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $B=(-1,1)\times(-\frac14,\frac14)\times \ldots\times (-\frac1{n^2},\frac1{n^2})\}\times\ldots$ is an open set in the box topology should be clear.
We have $$\begin{eqnarray}f(t)\in B&\iff &\forall n\in\omega\colon nt\in(-\frac1{n^2},\frac1{n^2})\iff\forall n\in\omega \colon t\in(-\frac1{n^3},\frac1{n^3})\\
g(t)\in B&\iff& \forall n\in\omega\colon nt\in(-\frac1{n^2},\frac1{n^2})\\
h(t)\in B&\iff &\forall n\in\omega\colon \frac1nt\in(-\frac1{n^2},\frac1{n^2})\iff\forall n\in\omega \colon t\in(-\frac1{n},\frac1{n})\\\end{eqnarray}$$
Since already$$\bigcap_{n\in\omega}(-\frac1n,\frac1n)=\{0\} $$
the claim follows and for all these functions the preimage of the opeb set $B$ is the non-open set $\{0\}$.

For uniform topology it is best not to think of open balls, but use convergence directly (after all that is the definition).

Comment: Would you please be able to say more about the three if and only if statements in your answer? and why are we looking at their intersection to give us their pre-image $\{0\}$ in this case

Answer (score 1):

Let $t \in \mathbb R$, $t \ne 0$. By the Archimedean property, we can find $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $0 < 1/n^2 < |t|$. But this means that the $n^\text{th}$ component of $f(t)$ (which is $t$) is *not* in the $n^\text{th}$ component of $B$ (which is $(-1/n^2, 1/n^2)$). Therefore $t$ cannot be in the pre-image of $B$. We conclude that the pre-image of $B$ is $\{0\}$ and $f$ is not continuous.

$g$ and $h$ can be handled similarly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why $nth$ component of $f(t)$ is not in $nth$ component of $B$

Comment: @JamesBond Well, if $|t| > 1/n^2$ then $t > 1/n^2$ or $t < -1/n^2$. Therefore $t$ is outside $(-1/n^2, 1/n^2)$. But the $n^\text{th}$ component of $f(t)$ is $t$, and the $n^\text{th}$ component of $B$ is $(-1/n^2, 1/n^2)$. For $f(t)$ to be in $B$, each component of $f(t)$ must be in the corresponding component of $B$.

Comment: But why are we looking at just the absolute value, $|t|$? Isn't t arbitrary?

Comment: @JamesBond We start with the absolute value of $t$ in order to apply the Archimedean property. We break up this into two cases (positive and negative) soon after.

Comment: So, we have the pre-image \{0\} because thats the only number inside such an open interval?

Comment: Yes, $0$ is the only number that is inside all of the components of $B$.