# Continuity in product, uniform, and box topologies

Tags: general-topology

Consider the product, uniform, and box topologies. In which topologies is each of the following functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^\omega}$ Continuous?

$f(t)=(t, 2t, 3t,\ldots)$;
$g(t)=(t,t,t,\ldots)$;
$h(t)=(t,t/2,\ldots)$;
$k(t)=(1,1,1,\ldots)$;

Using this,
[Pre-image of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524506/pre-image-of-continuous-functions)

I see that $f,g,h$ are not continuous with respect to the box topology. I’m guessing $k$ is continuous since constant functions are always continuous irrespective of the topology but not really sure how to show this using the type of open set they used in the link above. I suspected most of the functions would be discontinuous since the box topology is a finer topology than the other $2$.

What would the answer be in the product topology. In this topology infinitely many of the factors are the entire real numbers. Does that mean that all the functions will be continuous?

I don’t really understand the uniform topology or what an open ball looks like in this case? What would the answer be here?

Using this link

Comment: Answering your first question: If $X$ and $Y$ are two topological spaces, and $f : X \to Y$ is constant, say $f(x)=y_0$ for all $x \in X$, then $f$ is continuous for if $U$ is an open set in $Y$, then $f^{-1}(U) = \varnothing$ if $y_0 \notin U$ and $f^{-1}(U) = X$ if $y_0 \in U$. In any case, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: The product and box topologies are identical on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Did you mean $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, as in the linked question?

Comment: Yeah I mean in R^w in my question as well.